# Should I delete my own answer to a question that was closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure what the etiquette here would be. I'm a fairly new user, and saw a question that I knew the answer to, so I answered it. It has been since closed as a duplicate. (I'm a slow typer so I suspect it was closed *while* I was answering it.)

My answer was correct, but not nearly as in-depth as the accepted answer to the duplicate question, so it doesn't really add anything.

Should I delete it? Or does it no longer matter?

Comment: I'd personally delete the answer in this case, the duplicate question provides a pretty good reason for why. If your answer provides something new, I'd post it at the duplicate question.